# Query realm data contained on other object

Tags: android, realm, realm-list

This question is a follow-up question from: [Organize Android Realm data in lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38140827/organize-android-realm-data-in-lists)

Due to the data returned by the API we use, it's slightly impossible to do an actual query on the realm database. Instead I'm wrapping my ordered data in a `RealmList` and adding a `@PrimaryKey public String id;` to it.

So our realm data looks like:

```
public class ListPhoto extends RealmObject {
   @PrimaryKey public String id;
   public RealmList<Photo> list; // Photo contains String/int/boolean
}
```

which makes easy to write to and read from the Realm DB by simply using the API endpoint as the `id`.

So a typical query on it looks like:

```
realm.where(ListPhoto.class).equalTo("id", id).findFirstAsync();
```

This creates a slightly overhead of `listening/subscribing` to data because now I need to check `listUser.isLoaded()` use `ListUser` to `addChangeListener/removeChangeListener` and `ListUser.list` as an actual data on my adapter.

**So my question is:**

Is there a way I can query this realm to receive a `RealmResults<Photo>`. That way I could easily use this data in `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter` and use listeners directly on it.

**Edit:** to further clarify, I would like something like the following (I know this doesn't compile, it's just a pseudo-code on what I would like to achieve).

```
realm
 .where(ListPhoto.class)
      .equalTo("id", id)
      .findFirstAsync()  // get a results of that photo list
 .where(Photo.class)
      .getField("list")
      .findAllAsync(); // get the field "list" into a `RealmResults<Photo>`
```

**edit final code:** considering it's not possible ATM to do it directly on queries, my final solution was to simply have an adapter that checks data and subscribe if needed. Code below:

```
public abstract class RealmAdapter
                     <T extends RealmModel, 
                      VH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder> 
            extends RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<T, VH>
            implements RealmChangeListener<RealmModel> {

   public RealmAdapter(Context context, OrderedRealmCollection data, RealmObject realmObject) {
      super(context, data, true);
      if (data == null) {
         realmObject.addChangeListener(this);
      }
   }

   @Override public void onChange(RealmModel element) {

      RealmList list = null;
      try {
         // accessing the `getter` from the generated class
         // because it can be list of Photo, User, Album, Comment, etc
         // but the field name will always be `list` so the generated will always be realmGet$list
         list = (RealmList) element.getClass().getMethod("realmGet$list").invoke(element);
      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }

      if (list != null) {
         ((RealmObject) element).removeChangeListener(this);
         updateData(list);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: *Is there a way I can query this realm* what do you want to query exactly? The result of `realm.where(ListPhoto.class).equalTo("id", id).findFirstAsync();`?

Comment: @TimCastelijns yes. I would like a `RealmResults<Photo>` (or even directly the `RealmList`) that will match the `RealmList<Photo>` inside the `ListPhoto`. I know I could do it with a synchronous call. But I really rather use async.

Comment: I've edited the question with some pseudo-code. I hope it's more clear

Comment: I am not very satisfied with the final answer, so I need to ask: Can a photo belong to multiple ListPhoto?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce (epic nickname), I just realized that I can't access the field the way I was accessing. And deleted it. I'm still checking what I can do, but it shouldn't be much different from what u've seen before. But to answer your question: Yes. A photo belongs to only 1 user, but it can be in several albums, be on the popular photos list, it can show twice on the same album if `orderBy` is by `date` or `top`

Comment: I see,  one more question -  do you HAVE to use the async API for your query? Searching by primary key is really fast, even synchronously, and that would greatly simplify your issue.

Comment: On my current test that is just a few hundred items, I agree is being really fast (circa 25ms). And as I'm only calling once (during `onCreate`) I could make not async. But I'm one of those guys that deeply believes that every time an I/O operation happens on the UI thread a baby panda dies. So it doesn't HAVE TO be, but I really would rather not kill the cute baby pandas.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I've re-added my final code. This one works. Apparently accessing my declared field via reflection will always return null, so I had to do a slight hack-a-round. It's not great, but I still rather do that than using synchronous call.

Comment: Don't forget though, "few hundred items" is irrelevant in Realm because the query actually executes only for a given index, when you call `realmResults.get(i)`. So in reality, only the elements that are shown on the screen at a given time are queried from the Realm on sync API. Also, the field is always null because you have to use the proxy getter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you query the ListPhoto, because it's async you have to register a listener for the results. Then in that listener you can query the result to get a RealmResult.

Something like this

```
final ListPhoto listPhoto = realm.where(ListPhoto.class).equalTo("id", id).findFirstAsync();
listPhoto.addChangeListener(new RealmChangeListener<RealmModel>() {
    @Override
    public void onChange(RealmModel element) {
        RealmResults<Photo> photos = listPhoto.getList().where().findAll();
        // do stuff with your photo results here.


        // unregister the listener.
        listPhoto.removeChangeListeners();
    }
});
```

Note that you can actually query a RealmList. That's why we can call `listPhoto.getList().where()`. The `where()` just means "return all".

I cannot test it because I don't have your code. You may need to cast the `element` with `((ListPhoto) element)`.

Comment: thanks Tim. I was afraid that was the only answer. Like that I can't generate the RealmResult (or List) directly during `onCreate` and have to be awaiting for callbacks.

Comment: @Budius if you use async queries, yeah then you have to wait for the callback :-)

Comment: @Budius I had expected you to do the query in the activity or wherever, and pass the result of `RealmResults<Photo> photos = listPhoto.getList().where().findAll();` to the adapter instead of querying inside the adapter

Comment: It's a slightly more complex system, but the idea is that the adapter is created during `onCreate`. So I'm passing to the constructor `data.isLoaded()?data.getList():null` and case the list is null I listen to its changes. Currently I'm writing as a new sample code for this (https://github.com/eyeem/decorator) library we created while checking the viability to replace it into our app.

Answer (score 1):

I know you said you're not considering the option of using the synchronous API, but I still think it's worth noting that your problem would be solved like so:

```
RealmResults<Photo> results = realm.where(ListPhoto.class).equalTo("id", id).findFirst()
                           .getList().where().findAll();
```

**EDIT:** To be completely informative though, I cite the [docs](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmQuery.html#findFirstAsync--):

> findFirstAsync
>
> public E findFirstAsync()
>
> Similar to findFirst() but runs asynchronously on a worker thread This method is only available from a Looper thread.
>
> Returns: immediately an empty RealmObject.
>
> Trying to access any field on the returned object before it is loaded
>   will throw an IllegalStateException.
>
> Use RealmObject.isLoaded() to check if the object is fully loaded
>
> **or register a listener `RealmObject.addChangeListener(io.realm.RealmChangeListener<E>)` to be
>   notified when the query completes.**
>
> If no RealmObject was found after
>   the query completed, the returned RealmObject will have
>   RealmObject.isLoaded() set to true and RealmObject.isValid() set to
>   false.

So technically yes, you need to do the following:

```
private OrderedRealmCollection<Photo> photos = null;
//...

final ListPhoto listPhoto = realm.where(ListPhoto.class).equalTo("id", id).findFirstAsync();
listPhoto.addChangeListener(new RealmChangeListener<ListPhoto>() {
    @Override
    public void onChange(ListPhoto element) {
        if(element.isValid()) {
            realmRecyclerViewAdapter.updateData(element.list);
        }
        listPhoto.removeChangeListeners();
    }
}
```

Comment: could u explain how this would be different than directly using the list like this: `realm.where(ListPhoto.class).equalTo("id", id).findFirst().getList()`  I mean, if the list is already there, I don't need a second query, I can directly use the `RealmList<Photo>` object. No?

Comment: Well technically yes since I think 0.89.0 and the introduction of the `OrderedRealmCollection<T>` interface, but you said you wanted a `RealmResults<Photo>`, and this converts a list to a results. But that just makes your `list` be seen as a `view`, it doesn't actually cost anything to do the `.where().findAll()` conversion.

Comment: I wanted the `RealmResult` because the idea was to be able to get the whole thing async from the query. If it's to do synchronously, I'll just directly use the `RealmList`. Thanks a lot for the answers and comments. I'll need some time to balance the pros-cons between the approaches, but it have been very insightful. I wish I could mark both as correct.

Comment: I see. Well, I personally trust the synchronous API more, because the mechanism behind async queries is extremely complicated - and due to the lazy nature of queries (only the element you are querying is what gets evaluated), the sync API isn't slow either. Although I tend to recommend that if you're querying by a field, you should always put `@Index` on it - but `@PrimaryKey`s are `@Index` as well.